# Create label of disabled dropdown menues in AngularJs / Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I would like to implement a read-only mode for some of my views. Normally I would just disable the GUI-components, but I would like something that looks better. I have tried to remove the box and graphical stuff from dropdown menues, but I simply can't modify it enough.

So my question is, how could I make a directive in Angular which when applied to a disabled dropdown it will appear as a label?

Comment: yes it is possible :)

Answer (score 0):

Angular already has a directive that accomplishes this in declarative fashion.  `ng-show` will only display the tag it is attached to if the expression it is bound to is true.

You could do something like this (pseudo code):

```
$scope.mode = { 
  readonly: true
}

....

<div ng-show="mode.readonly">...</div>
<select ng-show="!mode.readonly">...</select>
```

Comment: yes this is a solution I have been using, however I would like to avoid it as I don't want to make an extra div for every input-element I have.